# Weird pattern of upvotes

Tags: discussion

I recently came across a user with such reputation changes:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I've flagged my own question for moderator attention regarding this. Is that the correct procedure?

Comment: You can flag your own question with a link to the user or one of the users own posts, as long as you're clear in your custom flag (the "in need of moderator intervention" option), they'll be able to figure it out

Comment: It is a common pattern for voting rings: a number of upvotes every day at approximately the same time of day. The more sophisticated voting rings launder the reputation points through the bounty system (to protect the reputation points).

Comment: The upvotes that occurred after the reputation cap is a bit odd. I'm not convinced that this is a voting ring. It could be a really stellar post. Or someone going for a tag badge by fraud. It's hard to tell.

Comment: @Scratte I’ve seen plenty of inexperienced accounts try out sock puppets and vote well past the rep cap. They only learned about the cap _after_ hitting it. Serial upvoting that blasts past the cap are not necessarily evidence that the voting wasn’t cast by socks!

Comment: Anyway, this specific case has been handled already, thanks for bringing it to our attention!